# PHP sql query not working to replace update all rows

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, sql-update

Trying to update table rows for a specific state_id the insert works but with an error, it doesnt use the right city_name ....

So this is what we tried and remember we are still learning PHP so any help would be appreciated

What it happening is its using the same city_name for every row instead of the actual one?

```
$selectquery = "SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE `state_id` = 9";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($selectquery);
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$city_name = !empty($row['city_name']) ? $row['city_name'] : '';

$new_key = "".$city_name." Businesses, ".$city_name." Business, ".$city_name." Tourism, .....";
$new_desc = "Find the best ".$city_name." Businesses. Find the best ".$city_name." Restaurants, ....";

$st3 = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE cities SET meta_desc = :desc, meta_key = :key WHERE state_id = 9');
$st3->execute([':desc' => $new_desc, ':key' => $new_key]);
}
```

Why is it no looping through each one?

Comment: You are, you're just overwriting every single city with the same data each loop, so you only see the values from the last loop. You probably want your update to use the city ID, not the state.

Comment: Can you provide us with an example? As we tried it that way to but it still using the wrong city_name for each row, and the citys are grouped by state_id if that helps

Comment: Well, if each city has an id, then you would do `WHERE id = :city_id` -- use the right column name, and make sure you grab the right city id in the loop. Pass it as a parameter since it would be different for each row

Comment: Thank you I got it using this  $st3 = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE cities SET meta_desc = :desc, meta_key = :key WHERE city_id = :id AND `state_id` = 9');
$st3->execute([':desc' => $new_desc, ':key' => $new_key, ':id' => $city_id]);

Answer (score 3):

We got it thanks to some guidance from  @aynber we used the following

```
$selectquery = "SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE `state_id` = 9";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($selectquery);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $city_name = !empty($row['city_name']) ? $row['city_name'] : '';
    $city_id = !empty($row['city_id']) ? $row['city_id'] : '';
    
    $new_key = "".$city_name." Businesses, ".$city_name." Business, ".$city_name." Tourism, P...";
    $new_desc = "Find the best ".$city_name." Businesses. Find the best ".$city_name." Restaurants, ...";
    
    $st3 = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE cities SET meta_desc = :desc, meta_key = :key WHERE city_id = :id AND `state_id` = 9');
    $st3->execute([':desc' => $new_desc, ':key' => $new_key, ':id' => $city_id]);
    }
```

I give you a thumbs up but dont know how?

Comment: Just FYI `$new_key = "".$city_name` could be simply `$new_key = $city_name` ...etc. Putting an empty string onto the start of the text doesn't do anything (because it's empty!)